# finding the ionic.zip.dll in dotnetzip

Tags: .net, dotnetzip

Sure I am being stupid but I can't find the ionic.zip.dll

On their [page](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip) I clicked on the download archive button. I have unzipped all the files but I can't see the dll. Clearly I am doing something wrong but what?

I have search the folder foe the file and nothing is returned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dll is within this download, it's just been renamed in a manifest, as can been viewed within the json file '\releases\releaseList.json'

To access the latest version, extract the following file:

```
'\releases\9\f8f1b2b3-518d-4802-ab92-ac64f37b6c85'
```

Rename this file to **'DotNetZipLib-DevKit-v1.9.zip'**

Within this zip there are a few different projects (I'm assuming zip-v1.9 is the .net zip package)

eg: **'\zip-v1.9\Release\Ionic.Zip.dll'**

Answer (score 1):

The legacy DotNetZip project was moved into the Archive on CodePlex.  To get the Ionic.Zip.Dll from the Archive download, some file manipulation is needed:

1. Extract the archive download.
2. Navigate to `\releases\9`
3. Locate the file called `5cea1d3e-6620-4516-b3db-ea1791d01f90`
   (the file mentioned in the other answer does not contain the dll)
4. In Windows Explorer, right-click the above file and select Copy (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste as a new file, and name it `tools.zip` or some other appropriate name
6. Double-click the `tools.zip` you just created, and you'll find not only the DLL you seek but also various compiled EXE's including the sample WinForm.

**NOTES**

- I'd have made this correction to the other answer but don't have sufficient reputation yet to do so.
- If you want the most up-to-date versions, you may consider alternatively using NuGet in Visual Studio to simply add DotNetZip to your project, and do an Imports Ionic.Zip
- The OP may not need this answer at this point, but I was just looking for this answer myself so I'm posting this in case it helps others.  However big thanks to @Radderz for getting me 90% of the way there.
- You'll find the DLL in some of the other files, too, but the one I mentioned has the other compiled tools as well, which might be useful.
- Don't overlook the license file - it's in one of the other accompanying files.